# Firefox does not start; could not create accelerators directory

Tags: firefox

`firefox` command throws this error:

> Could not create gnome accelerators directory `/home/username/.gnome2/accels': Permission denied.

It works with `sudo prepended`.

Should I change the directory's permission? e.g.

```
sudo chmod 777 accels
```

I cannot launch Firefox by clicking on its desktop icon either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, make sure you are the owner of the `accels` directory. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run :

```
sudo chown -R "$USER:$USER" "${HOME}/.gnome2/accels"
```

Then, try to launch `firefox` again.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing folder/file permissions, maybe you should go with changing the owner of folder. Set the ownership to ***username*** (from */home/**username**/.gnome2/accels*) with `chown` command:

```
chown -R username:group /home/username/.gnome2/
```

This way, all subfolders and files in /home/username/.gnome2 folder will be owned by ***username*** and appropriate group you specify.
*-R* switch stands for recursive (apply to all files/subfolders in folder command is ran for).